# Get delimiter in Irony

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, token, irony

I have the following rule in the grammar:

```
NonTerminal linker = new NonTerminal("linker");
NonTerminal list = new NonTerminal("list ");
NonTerminal item = new NonTerminal("item");

KeyTerm AND = ToTerm("AND");
KeyTerm OR = ToTerm("OR");

list.Rule = MakePlusRule(list, linker, item);
linker.Rule = AND | OR | Empty;
```

I get the list parsed correctly and returns a list of items as ChildNodes but I was wondering how can I get the "linkers" non-terminals as well?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a year, i hope you have already solved it. But for whoever in the same situation. You could try something like this,

    `list.Rule = expression | item;
    expression.Rule = list + linker + list
    linker.Rule = AND | OR | Empty;`